# Is $((A\to B)\land (\lnot A \to C))\equiv (A\lor C)$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm wondering whether $((A\to B)\land (\lnot A \to C)) \iff (A\lor C)$ is correct or not.

Comment: Have you tried using a truth-table?  If not, what else have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean B or C (not A or C)?

Comment: Since $(\lnot A \to C) \equiv (A\lor C)$, we have $((A\to B) \land (\lnot A \to C)) \rightarrow (A\lor C))$, But not vice-versa.  So the biconditional is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\neg A \Rightarrow C$ is equivalent to $A\vee C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the case $A:\text{true}$, $B:\text{false}$, $C:\text{any}$